# Checking services in parallel

Tags: powershell, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to check service status of almost 2K servers and restarting the service if it is in stopped status. I'm trying to do it with `foreach -parallel`, but it is not working. Also `$A.start()` is not supported by workflow.

```
workflow testWorkflow {
    foreach -parallel ($server in $servers) {
        $A = Get-Service W3SVC -ComputerName $server
        if ($A.Status -eq "Stopped") {
            $server | Out-File $FileName2 -Append
            $A.start() 
            Write-Host $A.name "Started Successfully on" $server 
        } elseif ($A.status -eq "Running") {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $A.name "is running"
        } elseif (!$?) {
            Out-File $FileName1 -Append -InputObject $server -Encoding Ascii
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at `-asjob` Parameter or `start-Job/get-job/receive-job` cmdlets.

Also you start the Service by using `start-service servicename`.

Comment: Jobs is bad for 2k servers, you better use runspaces, or workflows

Comment: @Avshalom Please elaborate.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Jobs is not really multithread, it use different PowerShell Process, with a thread per process, also the data is deserialized and the performance in that amount of servers and the overhead of the memory/cpu it needs make it not a good solution, instead I suggest using runspaces

Comment: @Avshalom Sounds interesting, can you give a reference? Didn't know that by now.

Comment: http://learn-powershell.net/2012/05/13/using-background-runspaces-instead-of-psjobs-for-better-performance/

Comment: In that case can someone suggest how to achieve this by using runspace?